# Best way to download documents from Web API - AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, security, asp.net-web-api, download, httphandler

I have an application developed in angularJs->ASP.NET Web Api. Now i have a requirement to download a secured file from server using the application. It document URL should be protected from unauthorized access too.

I'm thinking of using HttpHandler (ASHX file) in Web Api solution. I read that it helps us to protect the files when user try using the document URL with out privileges.

Any other options we have in Web Api to perform this? Any sample application would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: By any chance are those documents stored in S3?

Comment: @Michael - No. Those are located in server NAS storage. I need a common functionality which should validate the user identity even they try using the URL from a browser out side of application.